# Ajax in Plugins: returns the whole page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, wp-admin, javascript

I'm developing a small plugin for a client and my ajax calls returns the whole page as `json response`. I cannot find the bug.

In the plugin `main.php`:

```
function __construct(){
  //..
  $this->PluginSetup();
}

function PluginSetup(){
  //..
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_the_sag_form', array( $this , 'the_sag_form' ) );
}

function the_sag_form(){
  $response = "hello";
  wp_send_json($response);
}
```

In my main.js:

```
function init_inpage_functions(){
    var PageData = new FormData();
    PageData.append('action', 'the_sag_form');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: PageData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend:function(data){

        },
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    });

}
```

What's wrong? In the response I just received the whole page. Thanks.

Comment: Returns the whole of what page? `$reponse "hello";` will throw a parse error, as that's invalid syntax.

Comment: @Milo ok sure, that was a typo. Returns the html of the current option page. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `ajaxurl` is correct? If you manually visit the url via your browsers address bar, do you see the correct response?

Comment: Yes the url is correct. Going crazy. I'm investigating on possible variable conflicts.

Comment: @Milo there was a conflict with another ajax function. It was checking on `wp_doing_ajax()` and responding to all ajax requests. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

you are return simple a string in response variable that is not legitimate on the next line you are returning wp_send_json expect an array but you pass a variable.

Comment: I don't think you got the point and what you say is incorrect. I fixed anyways as you can read in the previous comments.